# connect gdal-java with tomcat

Tags: gdal, java, windows, tomcat, eclipse

I am trying to run:

```
SpatialReference poSourceSRS = new SpatialReference();
poSourceSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326);
String unit = poSourceSRS.GetAttrValue("UNIT");
System.out.println("unit: " + unit);
```

on a Tomcat 8(Run As.. -> Run on Server), which I linked to eclipse luna, and I get the tomcat error(in eclipse):

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [package.Servlet] in context with path [/myServlet] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gdal.osr.SpatialReference
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    at package.Servlet.showTileURL(Servlet.java:45)
```

But when I try to do the same in a java application (Run As... -> Java Application) it works..

I read [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018817/how-to-add-native-library-in-tomcat) about editing catalina.bat but they used Linux and I am on a Windows 7 64-bit. I don't know what I have to add to catalina.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different solution which you can read [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_add_JARs_or_classes_to_the_common_classloader_without_adding_them_to_.24CATALINA_HOME.2Flib.3F)